# How to extend twig template from parent bundle?

Tags: symfony, templates, inheritance, twig, bundle

I'm learning symfony2 and like it very much (migrating from ZendFramework 1.x) but I'm stuck now with twig templating. Can you point me to the right direction?

My application has many customers and each has some customization (mostly templates, but also controllers, etc.).

I try to achieve this by bundle inheritance / I created `ClientBundle` which inherits from `BaseBundle` holding all basic code and templates... it works as I need for everything bud templates. When I create template in `ClientBundle` it overlays the template from `BaseBundle` and I cannot get access from the `ClientBundle` template to the original template from `BaseBundle`. I would like to extend the parent template, not overlay it... is this impossible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Using the standard Symfony `extends` notation to reference a parent's bundle template results in fatal error. Symfony interprets your template reference to `BaseBundle` as `ChildBundle` as a result of bundle inheritance causing a function nesting level exception.

You can reference the parent's bundle template file directly using the following notation:

```
{% extends "@Client/Foo/bar.html.twig" %}
```

in replacement for:

```
{% extends "ClientBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig" %}
```

Twig's `FilesystemLoader` splits the reference string into **namespace** (Client) and **path** (Foo/bar.html.twig). Namespace is your bundle name without the Bundle suffix. Full path for each namespace is resolved by concatenating default `<bundle_path>/Resources/views/` with supplied **path**.

Comment: This is the correct solution. No dummy/base templates needed.

Answer (score 1):

The standard command in twig template for extention is:

```
{% extends 'BaseBundle::yourTemplate.html.twig' %}
```

You probably use the same name for template in your child bundle (you probably have a yourTemplate.html.twig in both your parent and your child bundle so the child template overrides the parent). In this case, you can rename your child template (yourTemplate2.html.twig) and then extend the child template from parent. More about bundles inheritance and twig templates extentions:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Yep, I want the template to be the same name... if I would change the name I would need to override also the corresponding action and change the template... I'm looking for something more elegant. Is there some solution?

Comment: even if you override the template you can still use the extend command. Did you try to include the {% extends ... %} line in your child template?

Comment: Yes I did / it ends in include loop. It doesn't include the parent template even if I use the parent bundle name in the extend :-(

Comment: In this case you can use a dummy template (tempTemplate.html.twig) in your child bundle to extend the parent template and then extend the dummy template in the child yourTemplate.html.twig, or even better create a baseYourTemplate.html.twig template in your app/Resources/views folder and extend both parent and child template from there.